# Install module "Devel" on Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I´m trying to install de Devel module of Drupal 8, I was reading the README.txt of Project/modules of Drupal, I have read this:

```
Placing downloaded and custom modules in this directory separates downloaded and
custom modules from Drupal core's modules. This allows Drupal core to be updated
without overwriting these files.
```

I have downloaded from the official website [Drupal - Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) the 8.x-1.x-dev version, to Drupal 8, and when I paste the module (after descompressed) in Project/modules, I have cleared the cache and Updates the "Extends" menu, but I can´t find my "Devel" module.

Do I need to install and configuring the FTP server?

Comment: shouldn't be a cache problem. for me works even without cache clean, just placing _devel_ folder under _modules_

Comment: What's the exact path to your devel module folder ? And is there a file named *devel.info.yml* inside ?

Answer (score 2):

just try with drush .

```
drush en devel -y
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using composer try

> composer require drupal/devel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try with
/admin/modules/install and let Drupal put it where it should be placed.